# MSBuild reset error flag

Tags: msbuild

I have a task that will always fail on the first call because its missing a file but I have an *OnError* Task which creates the file and it resumes the other tasks but the build will always fail because its in an error state. Is there anyway to reset this error state in the *OnError* Target?

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164285.aspx) states the following:

> MSBuild executes the **OnError** element if one of the **Target** element's tasks fails with the **ContinueOnError** attribute set to **ErrorAndStop** (or **false**)

That being said, I am unable to execute my task if I set the **ContinueOnError** to **WarnAndContinue** (or **true**)

Here is my code:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AppVersion>0.0.0</AppVersion>
    <ChangelogFileName>Changelog_$(AppVersion).html</ChangelogFileName>
    <AppCastLocation>http://test/AppCast.xml</AppCastLocation>
</PropertyGroup> 

<!-- AppCastCreation target is the starting point, it attempts to download
     the AppCast.xml (Target=AppCastDownload), if it fails then we create
     a new AppCast.xml (Target=AppCastNew) and then update the AppCast with
     the new version bneing deployed (Target=AppCastUpdate) -->
<Target Name="AppCastCreation">
    <CallTarget Targets="AppCastDownload;AppCastUpdate" RunEachTargetSeparately="True" />
</Target>

<Target Name="AppCastDownload">
    <!-- Download latest AppCast.xml if it doesn't exist, then create a new one -->
    <WebDownload FileUri="$(AppCastLocation)" FileName="AppCast.xml" />
    <OnError ExecuteTargets="AppCastNew"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="AppCastNew">
    <!-- Create a new AppCast.xml -->
    <Message Text="Creating new AppCast.xml" />
    <Exec Command='python $(AppCastPublisherPath)AppCastPublisher.py new AppCast.xml "Changelog" "$(AppCastLocation)"'/>
    <OnError ExecuteTargets="MessageErrorHandler"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="AppCastUpdate" DependsOnTargets="AppCastDownload">
    <Message Text="Updating AppCast.xml with Version $(AppVersion)" />
    <!-- Create changeset info and upload -->
    <Exec Command="python GetJenkinsChangeset.py -html -out $(ChangelogFileName)" />
    <OnError ExecuteTargets="MessageErrorHandler"/>
</Target>
```

So is there anyway i can reset the error state in my *AppCastNew* Target or potentially another workflow that would perform the same result?

Comment: You're mis-using the OnError task. Can't you simply check for the file before accessing it? This would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @D.R. How is _OnError_ being misused? It would be best if i check if the file exists beforehand but how can this be achieved with a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `<OnError...`, you can assign `ContinueOnError` the value [`"WarnAndContinue"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77f2hx1s(v=vs.110).aspx), and then use a condition to check the [`$(MSBuildLastTaskResult)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Old:

```
<WebDownload FileUri="$(AppCastLocation)" FileName="AppCast.xml" />
<OnError ExecuteTargets="AppCastNew"/>
```

New:

```
<WebDownload ContinueOnError="WarnAndContinue" FileUri="$(AppCastLocation)" FileName="AppCast.xml" />
<CallTarget Condition=" '$(MSBuildLastTaskResult)' == 'False' " Targets="AppCastNew"/>
```

(I believe both `"WarnAndContinue"` and `$(MSBuildLastTaskResult)` were introduced in MSBuild 4.0.)